# QueryDSL cross join with BooleanBuilder

Tags: spring, jpa, querydsl

Easy BooleanBuilder

```
booleanBuilder.and(QOrder.order.validationStatus.eq(ValidationStatus.ACCOUNTED))

.and(QOrder.order.orderAddress().id.isNull());
```

Generates cross join

```
from order order0_ cross join order_address orderaddr1_ where 
order0_.id=orderaddr1_.order_id and order0_ .validation_status=? and 
(orderaddr1_.order_id is null)
```

Thus it will never work as the cross join always return empty result set so the is null check never happen. Is there any other solution other than using JPAQuery directly?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: It is quite a while, but I suppose it has been rewritten without QDSL

Comment: Maybe we got rid of the cross join by specifying some hint for the DSL about the relation ship. Instead of using `.join(qAction.order().address()) `we used `.join(qAction.order(), QOrder.order)` and referenced address as  `QOrder.order.address()` making the order-address relation more obviouse for DSL query generator. If I remeber right there was no relationship so the DSL just made cross join without this.

Comment: Ok, I already tried both with no success but my query is generating cross join for a children of the joined entity. So there is no mean to specify the join explicitly. I guess the only ways is to specify it in the entity itself. Still with no success. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you send the query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163493/discussion-between-teikitel-and-zveratko).